# What do you call a statement like "How to perform a change of ownership"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests, terminology

What do you call a statement similar to the following?

> *"How to perform a change of ownership"*

I wish to request user input by asking a question such as:

> *"Please enter your title in the form of a ..."*

Comment: It's a statement, isn't it? "Please enter a single statement to use for the title, eg 'How to perform a change of ownership'."

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? I do not understand your question.

Comment: “How to perform a change of ownership” is not a statement; in particular, it has no subject.  But you could say,  “Please enter your title in the form of an adverbial phrase.”

Comment: What does “perform” mean? Cause? Bring about? Ride around a circus ring on a unicycle while dressed as a clown? :)

Comment: "Please enter your title in the form of..." is not a question; it is a command in the imperative mood akin to the jussive subjunctive.  

I think I understand "perform a change of ownership" with verbs like "to buy" and "to sell."

Comment: possible duplicate of [The grammatical function of "How"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31727/the-grammatical-function-of-how)

Comment: Well, the question is similar -- or at least the construction is -- but there's no useful answer there. The answer doesn't even mention the fact that this is an infinitive clause.

Comment: @JohnLawler It's not too late for you to fix that! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use such a phrase as the title of a document I give my software users to teach them how to perform a task.  I call it ***"instructions"*** or ****step-by-step instructions"*** or:

> ***"XYZ Software Training - How to Perform a Change of Ownership"***